# How can I sort arraylist and get index number at the same time

Tags: java, arraylist

I reverse sorted these elements and i want same sorting at the same time index by index

Like `s1.deposit.get(0) = 100` after sorting  index number would be 2 , i want Tom which is index number 0 at the beginning get 2 . How can I do that ?

```
s1.deposit.add(100);
s1.deposit.add(75);
s1.deposit.add(1890);
s1.deposit.add(25);
s1.deposit.add(360);

acc.named.add("Tom");
acc.named.add("John");
acc.named.add("Elena");
acc.named.add("Ralph");
acc.named.add("Carl");

Collections.sort(s1.deposit, Collections.reverseOrder());
int i = 0;
for(int counter: s1.deposit)  
    System.out.println(counter + " "+ acc.named.get(i));
    i++;
}
```

Comment: If you want two lists to have the same sort order when one is sorted, the typical solution is to combine the objects in the two lists into a single object, and sort those objects using a comparator on the sorted portion.

Comment: Please state the task you need to accomplish.  Is using 2 separate lists a requirement or your personal decision?

Comment: @RC. Maybe the question is a little bit unclear, but after I read it for two minutes, I understood what the requirement was. Throughout time, I've noticed an unpleasant, pedantic attitude from some members of the SO community to posters. I think that in this community, we should be driven by our will to help others, even in the case of unclear questions (which is not the case here). Sometimes, I've even noticed a rude attitude, which is not kind at all, especially to new posters.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner good for you if you did understand the question. And if you think my 1st comment is rude or unkind, flag it or don't read it..

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to have i.e. a `List<Person>` named `people` instead of your two separate lists `s1.deposit` and `acc.named`. The `Person` class could be as follows:

```
public class Person {

    private String name;

    private int deposit;

    // TODO: constructor accepting both fields, getters and setters
}
```

And list of people:

```
List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();

people.add(new Person("Tom", 100));
people.add(new Person("John", 75));
people.add(new Person("Elena", 1890));
people.add(new Person("Ralph", 25));
people.add(new Person("Carl", 360));
```

Then, sorting that collection would be straightforward:

```
Collections.sort(
    people,
    Comparator.comparing(Person::getDeposit).reversed());
```

However, if creating a class such as `Person` is not an option, you could still accomplish what you want with the help of a [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html), which sorts the entries by key:

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> indicesMap = 
    new TreeMap<>(Comparator.naturalOrder().reversed());

for (int i = 0; i < s1.deposit.size(); i++) {
    Integer deposit = s1.deposit.get(i);
    indicesMap.computeIfAbsent(deposit, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(i);
}
```

Here I'm using the [`Map.computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) method.

Once that map is filled, you only have to traverse its values:

```
indicesMap.values().stream()
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .map(acc.names::get)
    .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

I'm streaming the values of the map (which are lists), and then I use the [`Stream.flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) method to flatten the stream of lists to a stream that contains the elements of all lists, in sequence. Then I transform those indices into their corresponding names from the `acc.names` list via the [`Stream.map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) method, and finally print them.